# Existance and Uniqueness Theorem for PDE's

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for a general uniqueness theorem for linear second order PDE's. I would like to have general conditions for the boundary conditions.

For example, a very general formulation might look like,

For $ \hat{L} $ being a second order linear differential operator on functions $ f \in \mathit{H}^n \subset L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) $,

$$
\hat{L} \psi = S
$$
with $ S \in \mathit{H}^n $ has a unique solution for boundary conditions,

$$
\hat{\alpha}_i \psi \bigr|_{q_i = a_i} = f \in \mathit{H}^{n-1} \\
\hat{\beta}_i  \psi \bigr|_{q_i = b_i} = g \in \mathit{H}^{n-1}
$$
with $ \hat{\alpha}_i $ and $ \hat{\beta}_i $ first order linear operators.

Then ... (conditions of the various operators and functions) ...

A theorem with such generality would suffice for almost any problem I would encounter. My motivation is to avoid hand-waving (even if I keep it to myself) when solving problems.

Please refer me to something. Graduate level math preferred. Bonus points if it proves it only with the linear assumption of the operator (ie not necessarily second order)

EDIT:

Any theorem that comes remotely close to what I want will be appreciated. So far, school hasn't offered me any at all.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Kowalevski_theorem seems close to what I want, not exactly (unless I misunderstood). I would like a non local version.

Comment: You're not going to get such a theorem for a general operator. Look at this example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lewy's_example

Comment: Thank you. What about for specific operator classes? Hermitian operators I believe are always diagonalizable with real eigen values. It would seem then that if there is a basis for the solution, then conditions on the boundary conditions would determine where there is a solution or not.

Comment: If you have an operator that is uniformly elliptic with nice coefficients, meaning that the coefficient matrix $[a_{ij}(x)]$ is uniformly positive definite, and if you have a bounded region with a nice boundary, then you can say quite a bit, but not easily. Gilbarg and Trudinger has a lot of info, and Craig Evans has a graduate level PDE book with good information. Gilbarg and Trudinger is a demanding book. PDE theory is non-trivial and not all that clean. General symmetric is not strong enough. Coefficient matrices should be uniformly non-singular.